# Javascript map array promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I am trying to process all images in an array and push all of the processed images in other array.

The processing stuff runs async, so I am using await Promise.all to wait until all of the images has been processed. Anyways, the array is undefined when the code finishs.

Here is what I am doing:

```
async function processImage(image) {
    // ... stuff
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      (async () => {
        // Validate each image uploaded by the user
        const images = await Promise.all( // <--------------------------------
          imagesIds.map(async (id) => {
             // ... async stuff

            if(!error)
              return processedImage; // <-------------------------------
            else {
              reject(error);
            }  
          }
        }
        // ... stuff
        console.log(images); <-------- undefined
        resolve();
      })();
  }
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `async (resolve, reject)` is an anti-pattern.

Comment: `images` will never be `undefined`. `Promise.all` fulfills with an array or rejects, and not even your `// ... stuff` will be able to change the `const images`.

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572). And no, your edit of moving it to an IIEFE does not solve that problem.

Comment: I have created an async function and invoke it on the Promise.all(). Do you think it is correct? Just:   const images = await Promise.all(imagesIds.map((imageId) => processImage(imageId))

Comment: @Bergi but moving the async executor to an IIFE wouldn't solve the anti-pattern?

Comment: @Raul Yes, `const images = await Promise.all(imagesIds.map(processImage));` is totally fine. You don't need any of that `new Promise` or IIFE stuff around it.

Comment: @Bergi the thing is that it is an https callable function and I need to run this code inside a new Promise because the async function which is called in the map can throw errors which have to be rejected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219223/discussion-between-raul-and-bergi).

Comment: @Raul No, you don't need `new Promise`. If the async functions throw exceptions/return rejected promises, they will automatically reject the surrounding promise. You should just write `throw err;` it will work like the `return processedImage`.

Answer (score 0):

Promise.all takes an array of Promises that you want to be processed, so in this case, you want your imageIds.map function to return a list of promises. You do not need to do the async stuff in the map function, but just return a promise that can be taken care of by the Promise.all. One example is that if you are doing network requests for each image id have the map function `return fetch(yourEndPoint + id)` and the Promise.all function will handle the async processing.

See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: "*You do not need to do the async stuff in the map function*" - but the `async` is how the `map` callback returns a promise.